# Configuring ActiveMQ with Spring vs JNDI lookup

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

Folks- I have a Spring 3.1, ActiveMQ 5.8 & Tomcat7 setup.

Is there any advantage over configuring the factory & queues in Spring vs a JNDI lookup?

```
<amq:connectionFactory id="connectionFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
<amq:queue id="queueOne" physicalName="TestQueueOne"/>
<amq:queue id="queueTwo" physicalName="TestQueueTwo"/>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>   
<Resource 
    name="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
    auth="Container"
    type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
    description="JMS Connection Factory"
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

<Resource 
    name="jms/QueueOne" 
    auth="Container"
    type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" 
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
    physicalName="TestQueueOne" />

<Resource 
    name="jms/QueueTwo" 
    auth="Container"
    type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" 
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
    physicalName="TestQueueTwo" />
</Context>
```

I wonder if one method is "better" than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current setup with Tomcat perhaps Spring configuration is the way to go. If you were to move over to using a full blown application server, e.g. JBoss at some point then JNDI might be better as you could make use of a clustered JNDI for high availability offered by the application server:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/clustering-jndi.html